# please tell me about this exception

Tags: android

```
08-04 12:22:42.692: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(223): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
08-04 12:22:42.852: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(223): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
08-04 12:22:42.920: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(223): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
08-04 12:22:43.281: DEBUG/Eas Debug(223): Logging: 
08-04 12:22:43.311: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(223): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
08-04 12:22:43.961: DEBUG/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl64595.tmp
08-04 12:22:44.410: DEBUG/MediaScanner(197):  prescan time: 1014ms
08-04 12:22:44.430: DEBUG/MediaScanner(197):     scan time: 28ms
08-04 12:22:44.451: DEBUG/MediaScanner(197): postscan time: 1ms
08-04 12:22:44.461: DEBUG/MediaScanner(197):    total time: 1043ms
08-04 12:22:44.490: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(197): done scanning volume internal
08-04 12:22:45.060: INFO/PackageManager(58): Removing non-system package:com.ExtraCharge
08-04 12:22:45.390: DEBUG/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.ExtraCharge
08-04 12:22:45.390: INFO/PackageManager(58): Package com.ExtraCharge codePath changed from /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-2.apk to /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
08-04 12:22:45.421: INFO/PackageManager(58): /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk changed; unpacking
08-04 12:22:45.450: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk' ---
08-04 12:22:45.861: INFO/Launcher.Model(128): not binding apps: no Launcher activity
08-04 12:22:45.991: DEBUG/dalvikvm(128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4375 objects / 244016 bytes in 125ms
08-04 12:22:46.700: DEBUG/dalvikvm(245): DexOpt: load 154ms, verify 317ms, opt 14ms
08-04 12:22:46.741: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk' (success) ---
08-04 12:22:46.861: WARN/PackageManager(58): Code path for pkg : com.ExtraCharge changing from /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-2.apk to /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk
08-04 12:22:46.890: WARN/PackageManager(58): Resource path for pkg : com.ExtraCharge changing from /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-2.apk to /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk
08-04 12:22:46.890: DEBUG/PackageManager(58):   Activities: com.ExtraCharge.ExtraCharg com.ExtraCharge.ExactLogic com.ExtraCharge.Superheat com.ExtraCharge.Refri com.ExtraCharge.Help com.ExtraCharge.Info com.ExtraCharge.Subcooling com.ExtraCharge.Actual com.ExtraCharge.Actual1 com.ExtraCharge.Temprature com.ExtraCharge.Pressure
08-04 12:22:47.411: INFO/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.ExtraCharge-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.ExtraCharge-1.apk@classes.dex
08-04 12:22:47.671: DEBUG/PackageManager(58): New package installed in /data/app/com.ExtraCharge-1.apk
08-04 12:22:48.171: DEBUG/dalvikvm(128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8934 objects / 434544 bytes in 81ms
08-04 12:22:48.851: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.ExtraCharge uid=10038
08-04 12:22:48.851: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.ExtraCharge uid=10038
08-04 12:22:48.970: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.ExtraCharge uid=10038
08-04 12:22:49.111: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetProvider: pid=246 uid=10012 gids={3003}
08-04 12:22:49.531: DEBUG/dalvikvm(58): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8230 objects / 503368 bytes in 213ms
08-04 12:22:49.822: DEBUG/dalvikvm(163): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4393 objects / 264552 bytes in 876ms
08-04 12:22:50.011: INFO/ActivityThread(246): Publishing provider com.android.quicksearchbox.google: com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvider
08-04 12:22:50.220: DEBUG/dalvikvm(58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3195 objects / 161488 bytes in 130ms
08-04 12:22:50.341: INFO/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.ExtraCharge-2.apk@classes.dex
08-04 12:22:50.390: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(116): Shutting down VM
08-04 12:22:50.390: DEBUG/jdwp(116): adbd disconnected
08-04 12:22:50.470: INFO/AndroidRuntime(116): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-04 12:22:50.670: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(58): no available voice recognition services found
08-04 12:22:50.840: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaAppWidgetProvider: pid=256 uid=10022 gids={3003, 1015}
08-04 12:22:52.090: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.example.android.apis for broadcast com.example.android.apis/.appwidget.ExampleAppWidgetProvider: pid=264 uid=10034 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
08-04 12:22:52.500: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(259): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-04 12:22:52.500: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(259): CheckJNI is ON
08-04 12:22:52.930: INFO/ActivityThread(264): Publishing provider com.example.android.apis.SuggestionProvider: com.example.android.apis.app.SearchSuggestionSampleProvider
08-04 12:22:53.202: DEBUG/ExampleAppWidgetProvider(264): onEnabled
08-04 12:22:53.270: DEBUG/ExampleAppWidgetProvider(264): onUpdate
08-04 12:22:53.311: DEBUG/ExampleAppWidgetProvider(264): updateAppWidget appWidgetId=4 titlePrefix=Oh hai
08-04 12:22:53.372: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(259): --- registering native functions ---
08-04 12:22:53.461: DEBUG/ExampleAppWidgetProvider(264): onUpdate
08-04 12:22:53.461: DEBUG/ExampleAppWidgetProvider(264): updateAppWidget appWidgetId=4 titlePrefix=Oh hai
08-04 12:22:54.131: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=273 uid=10028 gids={}
08-04 12:22:55.001: INFO/ActivityThread(273): Publishing provider com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
08-04 12:22:55.770: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ExtraCharge/.ExtraCharg }
08-04 12:22:55.940: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(259): Shutting down VM
08-04 12:22:55.952: DEBUG/jdwp(259): adbd disconnected
08-04 12:22:56.071: INFO/AndroidRuntime(259): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-04 12:22:56.210: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.ExtraCharge for activity com.ExtraCharge/.ExtraCharg: pid=283 uid=10038 gids={}
08-04 12:22:57.420: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.ExtraCharge/.ExtraCharg: 1278 ms (total 32925 ms)
08-04 12:22:57.420: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 32930 ms (total 32930 ms)
08-04 12:23:05.762: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
08-04 12:23:06.031: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x3482f0:0x3483fc] in 5410717 ns
08-04 12:23:06.091: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x348400:0x3485c8] in 1399141 ns
08-04 12:23:07.401: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.ExtraCharge/.ExactLogic }
08-04 12:23:07.520: WARN/dalvikvm(283): VFY: invalid switch start: at 4, switch offset -25522, count 40550
08-04 12:23:07.520: WARN/dalvikvm(283): VFY:  rejected Lcom/ExtraCharge/ExactLogic;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
08-04 12:23:07.520: WARN/dalvikvm(283): Verifier rejected class Lcom/ExtraCharge/ExactLogic;
08-04 12:23:07.530: WARN/dalvikvm(283): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/ExtraCharge/ExactLogic;)
08-04 12:23:07.540: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(283): Shutting down VM
08-04 12:23:07.540: WARN/dalvikvm(283): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283): java.lang.VerifyError: com.ExtraCharge.ExactLogic
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-04 12:23:07.571: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 12:23:07.632: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.ExtraCharge/.ExactLogic
08-04 12:23:07.651: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.ExtraCharge/.ExtraCharg
08-04 12:23:07.951: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x3511c0:0x35127c] in 544577 ns
08-04 12:23:08.150: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44021928 com.ExtraCharge/.ExactLogic}
08-04 12:23:09.370: INFO/Process(283): Sending signal. PID: 283 SIG: 9
08-04 12:23:09.400: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Process com.ExtraCharge (pid 283) has died.
08-04 12:23:09.400: INFO/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{44012078 com.ExtraCharge/com.ExtraCharge.ExtraCharg paused=true}
08-04 12:23:09.511: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 283 uid 10038
08-04 12:23:18.781: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44020e70 com.ExtraCharge/.ExtraCharg}
08-04 12:23:18.833: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44021928 com.ExtraCharge/.ExactLogic}
```

Comment: Considering it is a FATAL EXCEPTION I would say it's bad :P

Comment: What comes on the line above the fatal exception. there is more to this error message?

Answer (score 3):

Question needs to be a little more clear, paste the part above the fatal exception too. Most of the times I have faced this problem was because I tried to print a string with null value. So it was more of a null pointer exception than anything else. Please post your code too, if you need an accurate account.

```
VFY: invalid switch start: at 4
```

I guess you are making some mistakes at this point because of which the error is coming. I am sorry but you do need to give the code for any more explanation!

Comment: no my problem is not solved if u give me ur id i will send u my code

Comment: I just sent you the address of the website where you can upload your code. Its free, create a new gist and paste your code there. That way you could just paste the link and every one can help you out.

Comment: but what is meaning of Invalid switch start

Comment: That I can tell you only when I see your code! Try debugging using Log.v("string","string");
This way you can check which functions are getting called and executed. You can also verify which line the problem is at with this method.